# Prove that set of all limit points of a connected set is connected

Tags: real-analysis

Looks to me that it should be true, although sets like 
$A = \{\frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ give me doubts

edit: I know it isn't a counter example but the fact that there exist sets such that their set of limit points is a point gives me doubts

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you mean A={1\n, n from N}?

Comment: The set $\{ \frac1n\colon n\in\Bbb N\}$ is not connected, and its set of limit points $\{0\}$ is connected; so this is far from a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be a connected set in a metric space. Then $A$ has no isolated points: if $x$ is an isolated point then $\{x\}$ is open and closed in $A$ contradicting connectedness.  Hence the set of limit points of $A$ is nothing but the closure of $A$. The closure of a connected set is always connected.